# Spree ship before confirm payment

Tags: spree

I have a stream of payment where I make a bank slip, then send the products and then confirm whether the ticket was paid.

In spree I need to confirm the payment before confirm the shipping.

Someone know can help me to find a way to confirm the shipping first and the payment after.

Spree 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just set `Spree::Config[:auto_capture_on_dispatch]` to `true`.

Then not only will it be possible to ship order before capturing payment (https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/shipment.rb#L121), but also payment will be captured automatically after shipping (https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/8bfa0824d2a7f6cfa6efc9bd4e32d1d564f6270b/core/app/models/spree/shipment_handler.rb#L22)